# Discriminated union on Opaque using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union

Typescript doesn't have a built-in `Opaque` type [like Flow does](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/). So I made my own custom `Opaque` type:

```
type Opaque<Type, Token = unknown> = Type & {readonly __TYPE__: Token}
```

It does the job, but at the same time, I'm losing the ability of [Discriminating Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). I'll give an example:

I have an array of animals and the following Opaque:

[image: animals constant]

[image]

So far so good. Right? well... not exactly. I'm using [assertNever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert-never) which helps me to assert a value as `never` (useful while discriminating unions):

```
export function assertNever(value: never): never {
    throw new Error(`Unhandled discriminated union member: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
}
```

But because of the `__TYPE__` property, I can't really "discriminate":

[image]

I have made [a simple demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-4jsxv) that demonstrates the issue, or you can view the full source here:

```
export function assertNever(value: never): never {
    throw new Error(`Unhandled discriminated union member: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
}

type Opaque<Type, Token = unknown> = Type & { readonly __TYPE__: Token };

const animals = ["Dog" as const, "Cat" as const];

type Animal = Opaque<typeof animals[0], "Animal">;


function makeSound(animal: Animal) {
    switch (animal) {
        case "Dog":
            return "Haw!";
        case "Cat":
            return "Meow";
        default:
            assertNever(animal);
            // ^^^ discriminated unions won't work.
    }
}

makeSound("Dog" as Animal);
```

A help or a suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I guess `typeof animals[0]` should rather be `(typeof animals)[number]` ... besides that I don't think that you can get the described behaviour, as the union of string literals and objects is weird ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it"s "weird"?

Comment: cause primitives don't have properties. That union cannot be fullfilled in reality. Therefore `"Dog"` does not match `"Dog" & { ... }` and therefore the discriminated union does not work.

Comment: I agree with you on this, but I can't find an alternative to implementing Opaque

Comment: Would [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwIYDOBwsAcsAG4kAUFeANksAFxwqUkCUr7VUcAbwBQcUXBgALKBADubYHICiUaVGqcA3EIC+QoTACeYYHADyYPAEcmAHgAqR4ABo4diAGtguALxxU7lFkUAD44XwdjOAAyQTgoYDwAExx6AzgAfXS7AE0ABUVM1jdPXG0tITQcAng8FEwAWwYCMLgAbQAiABEIAHN2-GbKlGqXdoBhPBh+wjgh6oBdcsNIgEE6xvoW8ytbZeAIBHx1ptaABnnRtYaGduCtZHQsHDhMAns4UBgvRObqqEwUD1gtQQKxagYXBQitw4CAXs07IIRGJ4jAkFBcHDvNi4BQtLoHhhsLhGp4AMoQVCJai1a70VhXDacJFiF6HaivGnHeijbp9TjM4Ss1mo9G4doACTwMgAhO0tKztB96MQ2XAOQQuXTRhMpgKWcLRKKMXB2gBZfYydoy5GiJXAFUmIWGgbEMgcNS0pkKsS6XRAA) work for you?

Comment: I don't understand why branded primitives don't get narrowed in the false branches of switch/case statements, but at least they do it properly with user-defined type guards.  ‍♂️.  I've spent some time looking for a related GitHub issue but haven't found one yet

Comment: @jcalz, that's far better than what I tried, but it's a bit painful to write it all over the app. Maybe TS will come up with a solution in the days to come. In any case, I highly appreciate the time and effort it took from you!

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to figure out why your `Opaque<T, U>` type doesn't properly get narrowed via control flow analysis when using `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` statements.  When you pass in a primitive datatype for `T` in `Opaque<T, U>`, like in `Animal` with `"Cat" | "Dog"`, you get what's called a "branded primitive", as mentioned [in this FAQ entry about making nominal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  What seems to be happening is when you have a branded primitive `val` and use a regular type guard check against another primitive value `somePrimitive`, such as `if (val === somePrimitive) { /*true*/ } else { /*false*/ }` or `switch (val) { case somePrimitive: /* true */ break; /*false*/` }, everything is fine in the "true" part of the check: the type of `val` is narrowed to something like [`Extract<`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu)`typeof val, typeof somePrimitive>`.  So in your case, `if (animal === "Dog") { /*true*/ } else { /*false*/ }` is narrowed to `Opaque<"Dog", "Animal">` in the true branch.

What is *not* fine is what happens in the "false" part of the check.  If `val` is *not* equal to `somePrimitive`, then we should be able to narrow it to [`Exclude<`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu)`typeof val, typeof somePrimitive>`.  That is, when `animal` is not equal to `"Dog"`, the compiler should narrow `animal` to `Opaque<"Cat", "Animal">`.  But that's not happening.

Somtimes in checks like this it's correct not to narrow in the false branch.  For example, when your types are not singletons and can have more than one valid value of that type.  If I had `function f(x: string | number) { if (x === "Dog") { /*true*/ } else { /*false* } }`, it makes sense to narrow `x` to `string` (or even `"Dog"`) in the true branch, but you wouldn't want to narrow `x` to `number` in the false branch.  The safest thing to do when the compiler doesn't know exactly what's going on is to narrow in the true branch and not to narrow in the false branch.

But I didn't expect to see the compiler taking this route in the case of a branded primitive.  It's not possible for the type of `animal` to be `Opaque<"Dog", "Animal">` once you have `animal !== "Dog"`.  So I'm inclined to file a GitHub issue about this and see what they say; it feels like either a bug or at least a design limitation.  I'm kind of surprised I haven't seen this come up before and that I can't find a directly relevant  issue already filed.  Oh well.

---

So, what workarounds are possible?  One is to make a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  User-defined type guards are generally treated by the compiler such that even a `false` result implies a narrowing of the parameter.  This is not always desirable (see [microsoft/#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048) for a suggestion to allow such type guard functions to be more configurable so that `false` returns are not narrowed), but it's what you want here.  It could be implemented like this:

```
function is<T extends string>(x: any, v: T): x is T {
    return x === v;
}
function makeSound(animal: Animal) {
    if (is(animal, "Dog")) {
        return "Haw!";
    } else if (is(animal, "Cat")) {
        return "Meow"!
    } else {
        assertNever(animal); // no error now
    }
}
```

This works.  Of course, as you mentioned, it requires a refactoring of all your `switch`/`case` statements to function-calling `if`/`else` statements, so it could be too painful.

---

Ideally TypeScript would support a more official opaque/nominal type, such as the [`unique` type brand proposal in microsoft/TypeScript#33038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038).  But for now the simplest workaround I can think of here that lets you keep your `switch` statements is to use a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums).

Normally I don't recommend using enums at all, since they have strange caveats and don't conform to the current [design methodology of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (enums are runtime functionality not present in pure JavaScript, running afoul of non-goal #6)... but at least they behave as intended when used as a discriminant:

```
enum Animal {
    DOG = "Dog",
    CAT = "Cat"
}

function makeSound(animal: Animal) {
    switch (animal) {
        case Animal.DOG:
            return "Woof!"; // English-speaking dog 
        case Animal.CAT:
            return "Meow!";
        default:
            assertNever(animal); // no error
    }
}
```

Here your `Opaque`, `animals`, and `Animal` are replaced by the single `Animal` enum. Note that in `makeSound` we have to test against `Animal.DOG` and `Animal.CAT` instead of against `"Dog"` and `"Cat"`.  The compiler still won't do the false-case narrowing otherwise.  Luckily checking against the enum values *does* work.

---

So, those are my thoughts.  Hope they help you proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVKEBOARCAzAlsBACYAqAnjBAOICuIGxSA3gFBIdIQAeMA9hgAuSXLWDxB+PsCQgo6IQDkIAN0wAKFSAA2tCAC4kRNRgCUh45hbtOtwQAsMfAO5GIrgKIYnGdaYDcNhwAvqxBSIKUyADycACOegA8FFQANEikfADWEDIAvEhiWcAuwAB8SAUpyABkLEgYECDE0trkSAD6HaQAmgAKHl2GmTkywYHh8NJQwiDA+GA6UJVIANoARFh8AObrsstTwDPp6wDCIIJ7ckiHMwC6E3ZRSACC84vaK7EgCRCJkVQ+LhZO8lqsAAx3E5vBY6dZlR6cW6zFYbLa7fZIb6-RKbHbraGg7Twk7nS6Y7FJM4XAlIdYwj7wu6Y5GIjiicSSaRIfBQZJcbiCXLEZYzDCEbZldTcQxzcjpFTDcxIbg85akay2WyNQS0DAyVV5I1IFSBWyhWwciRSGSLHIAZT4YmI6jmsO0hgZOlMmq1HHwwPUvNdRJO6PWph9bD9fp1epk6wAEiBnABCdZmmPBLjadA8wPBt0fUk0yO+mOcOP6ukAWQgLnWqfC5pzeejFc4cgUgmUJhD7oCzc4FuHYVYoVYoEgsAQyA8wFoYGs4R4-CEIjE1u5XcwPdUGi0ugMbhMyssGHLWocTlcRE83gEfkzITCtlyi9eRMvtiw0WoKzxXZUiHDhTheDUCmpS5wgnS1Ny5W0QAdJ1gBdIsdE9IkoxApAoGcfBBHgewkH7D5sI7JE5GQL1tAAOl-ah9BwisqwTAB1PggXTfwkAAel4pB522bReXsABaWAmiyCUkBabYkGYyi8xo2iwNIJiKNjCBdWrdY6xcbjFI4Yg8BAWhtEEDTNNsHclH3Xx0O0QcKxHF9xyAA)

Comment: In what language do dogs go "Haw"?